# Using re.compile to get strings

Tags: regex, python-2.7

In my code below, if I use re.compile, it works fine as follows:

```
 name = 'hi over there, how are you and hello there'
 name1 = ['hi', 'hello', 'hello there', 'howdy', ]
 regex1 = re.compile(r'\b(%s+.])\b'%'|'.join(name1))
 name3 = re.findall(regex1, name)
 print name3 ##python27
output >> 'hi', 'hello'
```

How can I output only **'hello there'**

Comment: in which condition you want hello there? if its static word or index can use idnex instead.. or is their any specific reason to use regex? will help to sort out

Comment: am using a certain system of matching words, some singular(one word), some multiple(ngrams)